# Is it not possible to create a UIViewController programmatically without building the view?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I want to create a UIViewController programmatically. No nibs or storyboards. It will basically be created and then presented, and in its own class it will set up an image to be displayed.

However, whenever I just `alloc init` a view controller and present it, it comes out black as it is presented.

I assume this is because it lacks its own view?

When I create a raw `UIViewController` in Storyboard it automatically sets it up with a view, how do I set the view up so like the Storyboard it's the proper device size, changes on rotation, etc.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, whenever I just alloc init a view controller and present it, it comes out black as it is presented.

Because it is just a raw UIViewController. You have no way to modify / customize it; it isn't your class.

Instead, create a UIViewController *subclass*, e.g. MyCoolViewController, and instantiate and present *that*. The difference is that with MyCoolViewController you can override `viewDidLoad` and other methods so as to put some useful interface into its `view`.

> how do I set the view up so like the Storyboard it's the proper device size, changes on rotation, etc

Don't worry; all that will happen automatically, because the view is managed by a view controller and the view controller is placed correctly into the view controller hierarchy (e.g. by saying `presentViewController:...`).

Comment: My book teaches you how to customize a view controller subclass's view, and gives you some code to play with; start here: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch19.html#_manual_view

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say I'm using a subclass. I create the subclass with alloc init, present it, and it's black. I assume unlike a custom UIPageViewController subclass for instance I have to set things up myself? How do I specify the view to be the proper size of the device and rotate accordingly? Should I be doing it in loadView?

Comment: You don't. Merely saying `presentViewController:...` will take care of everything. It is no business of a view controller what its view's size will be when placed into the interface; that is handled by its parent.

Comment: I'll upload an example project shortly then. I seem to be doing just that.

Comment: Here's an example project: http://cl.ly/0B3S1E0n1v3j I create the subclass, then present it, but it's black.

Comment: I understood the question - your example project adds nothing that I didn't already know. Did you try reading my answer and my comments above?

Comment: Yes. You said "Merely saying presentViewController:... will take care of everything." Does everything have an asterisk?

Comment: What on earth is this really about? I told you: you haven't put any interface into your custom view controller's view, so it is a default black view. When you do, you'll see that interface. Why don't you _try_ it, for heaven's sake? Even just adding `self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()` in your `viewDidLoad` would show you that my answer is true. I've written you a whole book that explains all this to you - and I gave you a link where you can read it online. Why don't you read what I've written?

Comment: It's about my view controller showing up? It being black indicated to me that because when you add a view controller without customization the view is white, that there must be an issue. I'm away from my computer and it didn't occur to me that they simply chose a different colour. Geez.

Comment: Geez indeed. - Also, your question "set the view up so like the Storyboard it's the proper device size" is completely misconceived; the storyboard size of the view has _nothing_ to do with the size it will be when the view is loaded at run time. The storyboard has no effect upon the view size, any more than the view controller does.

Comment: IF you haven't yet, please check out my answer.  I explain exactly what's going on and why you're seeing the black background.  Hopefully it will clarify things better for you. :)

Comment: @MarqueIV You've given your answer. There's no need to bang on _my_ answer with your unconstructive comment.

Comment: @Matt, I respectfully disagree.  The comment chain here clearly shows there was some confusion here.  That and your answer is technically wrong because there is plenty of ways to modify both the ViewController and its associated view externally and without subclassing either, which I demonstrate below.  So again, I respectfully disagree, but thanks for your comment.

Comment: Also, your comment about the view size not being dictated by the storyboard/nib is also technically incorrect.  Without any external constraints and such, if you have a view loaded from a nib, it absolutely uses the design-time size.  The difference is when it's loaded, more times than not, ViewControllers are used for full-screen views and in that case, yes the size isn't dictated by the design-time size.  But try it with a child/subview.  Load it from a nib, then add it to the main view.  That subview will be loaded at the exact design-time size as seen in IB because nothing overrides it.

Answer (score 5):

Hoping this answer clarifies a few things here, even though there's already an accepted answer. I didn't feel the explanation given there was clear enough, which was probably why the OP didn't follow it at first, causing the OP more confusion and the answerer to get snarky in the comments, which doesn't help anyone. That's not what this site is all about.

> Whenever I just alloc init a [UIViewController] and present it, it comes out black as it is presented.

It's not actually black. It's transparent (or more accurately, its *view* is) so what you're really seeing is the black from whatever is behind the view (in this simple case, most likely the `UIWindow` itself.)

This is because you are relying on the default implementation of `loadView` in your `UIViewController` which simply creates a `UIView` instance, and a `UIView`'s background property is `nil` by default, hence it's transparent.  When you set this up in interface builder however, it usually sets the `backgroundColor` property to white for you.

You can of course simply do this yourself in code.  Here's an example showing exactly that except I'm using green instead of white so when you present it, you know for sure you're seeing this specific view:

```
UIViewController* plainViewController = [UIViewController new];
plainViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
```

Of course it doesn't make much sense to use a `UIViewController` without subclassing it, but you can. You just have to manage everything externally, just as I did above.

If you *do* subclass `UIViewController`, you simply implement your own `loadView` implementation to create your own `UIView` (or subclass), but remember, there too it will be transparent unless you explicitly set its `backgroundColor` as well.  Here are a few ways to do exactly that...

In your own `UIViewController.m` subclass, to initialize the background with the default `UIView` instance...

```
- (void) loadView
{
    [super loadView]; // Actually loads and assigns the default view

    // Set the background on the default view
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
}
```

or to use a custom `UIView` subclass...

```
- (void) loadView
{
    // Create and initialize your custom view
    MyCustomUIView* myCustomUIView = [MyCustomUIView new];
    myCustomUIView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

    // You're setting the view so do *not* call [super loadView]
    self.view = myCustomUIView;
}
```

You can also initialize the background in `viewDidLoad`, like so (this works for either of the versions above.

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    // Set the background on whatever view is being managed
    // regardless of where/how it was created
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
}
```

Note: when using `viewDidLoad`:

1. In the first case above, you can simply delete `loadView` entirely as it's not needed as `super` will now handle creating the view.
2. In the second case, you leave `loadView` but delete the line where you're setting the `backgroundColor` property since you're now doing that in `viewDidLoad`.

The benefit with all three of these approaches however is now the view's initialization is contained within your `UIViewController` making reuse much easier.

On a side note, a `UIWindow` is itself a subclass of `UIView`, and thus, it also has a `backgroundColor` property (which is also `nil` by default of course.) As such, if you change the `backgroundColor` property of the window to say purple, that's what you would have seen instead of black (that is until you set the background color on the view, which completely covers the window.)

> I assume this is because it lacks its own view?

Hopefully the above-stated reasons clarified this assumption is wrong.  It is actually there, just transparent.

The act of simply accessing the `view` property of a `UIViewController` will create the view if it doesn't exist already.  Since presenting a newly instantiated `UIViewController` requires accessing its `view` property to have something to actually present, that is when the view is created.  However, in the case above where I explicitly access the `view` property so I can set the `backgroundColor` property on it, *that* was the point in time when the view was created.

Anyway, hope this clarifies a little more what you were seeing and what's actually going on behind the scenes.  Its actually pretty simple to create and use ViewControllers programmatically once you get the hang of it.  Even so, it's still far easier to use storyboards or even NIBs with Interface Builder since you can visually see what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/):

> If you cannot define your views in a storyboard or a nib file,
>   override the loadView method to manually instantiate a view hierarchy
>   and assign it to the view property.